# C++ initialization of non constant static member variable?

Tags: c++, static, constants

I got a qualification error of the member variable 'objectCount'. The compiler also returns 'ISO C++ forbids in-class intialization of non-const static member'.
This is the main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Tree oak;
    Tree elm;
    Tree pine;

    cout << "**********\noak: " << oak.getObjectCount()<< endl;
    cout << "**********\nelm: " << elm.getObjectCount()<< endl;
    cout << "**********\npine: " << pine.getObjectCount()<< endl;
}
```

This is the tree class which contains the non-const static objectCount:

```
#ifndef TREE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREE_H_INCLUDED

class Tree
{
    private:
        static int objectCount;
    public:
        Tree()
        {
            objectCount++;
        }
        int getObjectCount() const
        {
            return objectCount;
        }
    int Tree::objectCount = 0;
}
#endif // TREE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: There is another alternative that wasn't mentioned in any of the suggested answers at the time of this writing, which allows you to **keep** everything in a **single header**. See the example in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618854/3041008), it maps perfectly to your example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to define the static variable in the source file that includes this header.

```
#include "Tree.h"

int Tree::objectCount = 0;  // This definition should not be in the header file.
                            // Definition resides in another source file.
                            // In this case it is main.cpp
```

Comment: there is still the following error 'two or more data types in declaration of objectCount'

Comment: I forgot to put this line int `Tree::objectCount = 0;` outside the class and I forgot to end the header class with semicolon
thank you

Comment: Why does this variable have to be declared outside of the class? I am trying to define and initialize a private variable, and I am getting this same error. How do I do this outside the class?

Comment: @DavidFaux Show what are you trying to do. Only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class.

Answer (score 5):

```
int Tree::objectCount = 0;
```

The above line should be outside the class, and in `.cpp` file, as shown below:

```
//Tree.cpp 
#include "Tree.h"

int Tree::objectCount = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define it outside the scope in a single C++ file, not in the header.

```
int Tree::objectCount = 0;
int main()
{
    Tree oak;
    Tree elm;
    Tree pine;

    cout << "**********\noak: " << oak.getObjectCount()<< endl;
    cout << "**********\nelm: " << elm.getObjectCount()<< endl;
    cout << "**********\npine: " << pine.getObjectCount()<< endl;
}

#ifndef TREE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREE_H_INCLUDED

class Tree
{
    private:
        static int objectCount;
    public:
        Tree()
        {
            objectCount++;
        }
        int getObjectCount() const
        {
            return objectCount;
        }
}
#endif // TREE_H_INCLUDED
```