# error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static, language-lawyer

this is the header file: employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
public:
    Employee(const string &first, const string &last)
```

Overloaded Constructor

```
    : firstName(first),
```

firstName overloaded constructor

```
      lastName(last)
```

lastName overloaded constructor

```
    { //The constructor start
    ++counter;
```

it adds one plus per each object created;

```
    cout << "Employee constructor for " << firstName
         << ' ' << lastName << " called." << endl;
    }

    ~Employee() {
```

Destructor
            cout << "~Employee() called for " << firstName << ' '
                 << lastName << endl;

Returns the first and last name of each object

```
        --counter;
```

Counter minus one

```
    }

    string getFirstName() const {
        return firstName; 
    }

    string getLastName() const {
        return lastName;
    }

    static int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

   static int counter = 0;
```

Here is where i got the error. But, why?

```
};
```

principal program: employee2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "employee2.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Number of employees before instantiation of any objects is "
         << Employee::getCount() << endl;
```

Here ir call te counter's value from the class

```
    {
```

Start a new scope block

```
        Employee e1("Susan", "Bkaer");
```

Initialize the e1 object from Employee class

```
        Employee e2("Robert", "Jones");
```

Initialize the e2 object from Employee class

```
        cout << "Number of employees after objects are instantiated is"
             << Employee::getCount(); 

        cout << "\n\nEmployee 1: " << e1.getFirstName() << " " << e1.getLastName()
             << "\nEmployee 2: " << e2.getFirstName() << " " << e2.getLastName()
             << "\n\n";
    }
```

end the scope block

```
    cout << "\nNUmber of employees after objects are deleted is "
         << Employee::getCount() << endl; //shows the counter's value
} //End of Main
```

What is the problem?
I have no idea what's wrong.
I have been thinking a lot, but a i do not what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants, since counter is being modified later.

Comment: @PMF:  Yeah, you're right!

Comment: I want initialize _counter_ and later increment it with the constructor. Then decrement it with the destructor.

Comment: I don't think the error message can be any clearer.

Comment: @texasbruce The error message only tells you what's wrong, not how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The *initialization* of the static member `counter` must not be in the header file.

Change the line in the header file to

```
static int counter;
```

And add the following line to your employee.cpp:

```
int Employee::counter = 0;
```

Reason is that putting such an initialization in the header file would duplicate the initialization code in every place where the header is included.

Comment: I did it, but it returns: In function ‘int main()’:
error: ‘int Employee::counter’ is private
error: within this context

Comment: @user3053929: Where did you put it? It needs to be outside any function but where the class Employee is known. BTW: Why is your cpp file called employee2.cpp? And including employee2.h?

Comment: Because i did another one. But it does not matter. Thank for the info

Comment: if that's sole reason why it's prevented, why const members are allowed? Don't they get initialized in every place where the header is included aswell?

Comment: @JesusChrist: Not sure. Either it wouldn't matter if the const member got a new memory location every time (in fact existing multiple times) or not at all (because it gets eliminated by the compiler)

Comment: this is right if the class is defined in a header(h) file but if the class is defined in the code(cc) file this is just an extra unnecessary step.

Answer (score 6):

According to [a similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31608148/3041008) there is another approach, in particular suited for your current implementation (header-only library):

```
// file "Employee.h"
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

class Employee {
public:
    Employee() {
        getCounter()++;
    }
    ~Employee() {
        getCounter()--;
    }

    static auto getCount() -> std::size_t {
        return getCounter();
    }
private:
    // replace counter static field in class context,
    //    with counter static variable in function context
    static auto getCounter() -> std::size_t& {
        static std::size_t counter = 0;
        return counter;
    }
};

#endif //EMPLOYEE_H
```

I took the liberty to use [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for representing the non-negative employee count and [trailing return syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11215227/3041008) for functions.

Accompanying test ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/6xN0h3)):

```
#include "Employee.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Initial employee count = " << Employee::getCount() << std::endl;
    // printed "count = 0"

    Employee emp1 {};
    std::cout << "Count after an employee created = " << Employee::getCount() << std::endl;
    // printed "count = 1"

    {
        Employee emp2 {};
        std::cout << "Count after another employee created = " << Employee::getCount() << std::endl;
        // printed "count = 2"
    }
    std::cout << "Count after an employee removed = " << Employee::getCount() << std::endl;
    // printed "count = 1"

    return 0;
}
```